# How do I improve the performance in parallel computing with dask

Tags: python, list, pandas, dask

I have a pandas dataframe and converted to dask dataframe

df.shape = (60893, 2)

df2.shape = (7254909, 2)

```
df['name_clean'] = df['Name'].apply(lambda x :re.sub('\W+','',x).lower(),meta=('x', 'str'))
names = df['name_clean'].drop_duplicates().values.compute()

df2['found'] = df2['name_clean2'].apply(lambda x: any(name in x for name in names),meta=('x','str')) ~ takes 834 ms

df2.head(10) ~ takes 3 min 54 sec
```

How can I see the shape of dask dataframe ?

Why it is so much time for .head() ? Am I doing it in the right way ?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "How do I create a list of names to iterate over it".  The result of `.values` is a [dask.array](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/array.html).  Perhaps you want to call `.compute()` instead of `.values`?

Comment: I need to compare the values(string comparison) in the list with data frame column.So I need to iterate the list

Comment: Thanks Rocklin ! able to do it , but when I want to see the output it takes lot of time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not iterate over a dask.dataframe or dask.array.  You need to call the `.compute()` method to turn it into a Pandas dataframe/series or NumPy array first.

Note just calling the `.compute()` method and then forgetting the result doesn't do anything.  You need to save the result as a variable.

```
dask_series = df.Name.apply(lambda x: re.sub('\W+', '', x).lower(), 
                            meta=('x', 'str')
pandas_series = dask_series.compute()

for name in pandas_series:
    ...
```